# skill sets required to become a sharpoint 2013 architect

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

what are the skill sets required to become a SharePoint 2013 architect?

Answer (score 1):

Their are couple type of Architect.

**Solutions Architect:**The role of a solution architect is primarily selecting the methods and features in a solution.[you'll need `C#\VB & ASP.NET` is a must for custom development and Common web development stuff like (HTML, CSS & JavaScript).](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127778/knowledge-and-skills-required-for-sharepoint)

**Infrastructure Architect**: an infrastructure architect work on topology design, selecting the right topology, server types, networking infrastructure, and so on.

**Business Architect**:A business architect would look more at the soft skill requirements, mapping business processes to the right process management tools, finding the right information architecture, and so on.

[The Role of a SharePoint Architect](http://blog.furuknap.net/the-role-of-a-sharepoint-architect)

[Become a SharePoint Professional – Understanding The Architect Role](http://blog.furuknap.net/become-a-sharepoint-professional-understanding-the-architect-role)